# Is it possible to use a where clause in a Laravel collection that has been called via a get() function

Tags: laravel

As the above question; Is there any way possible to use a where clause on a Collection?

These are my codes;

```php
$order = \App\Order::where('user_id', $input['user_id'])
->whereBetween('created_at', array($date_from_formatted, $date_to_formatted))
->get();
```

**Note that when i dd($order) my collection returns just fine**

```php
$online_order = $order->where('ord_type', 'Onl')
                ->where('paid', 'Y')
                 ->whereIn('status', $param);
$online_order->all();
```

**Note that when i dd($online_order) i get an empty collection**

Am i doing something wrong with my $online_order?

Comment: your code is fine, i think maybe just no datas adapt to these condition

Comment: there is data, when i change my `$order` to `$order = \App\Order::where('user_id', $input['user_id'])->where('ord_type', 'Onl')->where('paid', 'Y')->whereIn('status', $param)->whereBetween('created_at', array($date_from_formatted, $date_to_formatted))->get();` it returns the data to me, the reason why im splitting it apart is due to some date filtering later.

Comment: `$online_order->all();` should return the all data. no other conditions will appiled on it.

Comment: @hasan05 no, it is applied on collection, so it will return array

Comment: can u post your tables' structure?

Comment: `protected $fillable = [
        'invoice_no',
        'receipt_no',
        'user_id',
        'company_id_for_user',
        'sub_total',
        'gst_total',
        'shipping_total',
        'shipping_reduced',
        'discount',
        'total',
        'full_name',
        'order_type',
        //'discounted_total',
        'paid',
        'status',
        'created_at',
        'created_by',
        'preferred_day'
    ];`

Comment: @UdhayanNair no, I means the table's field, is there some uppercase, something like `Ord_type`?

Comment: nope, all lowercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make `$order` to  model instance so you can use `where()` with it

```php
$order = \App\Order::where('user_id', $input['user_id'])
        ->whereBetween('created_at', array($date_from_formatted, $date_to_formatted));
orderValue = $order->get();
```

and other

```php
$online_order = $order->where('ord_type', 'Onl')
                ->where('paid', 'Y')
                 ->whereIn('status', $param);
$online_order->all();
```

Comment: still the same mate

Comment: the collection returns an empty array,` Collection {#1255 ▼
  #items: []
}`

Comment: you can debug but `toSql()` function  insted of `get()` the value and run that sql to mysql and check

Answer (score 0):

Try by this way. May be it will solve your problem.

```
$query = \App\Order::where('user_id', $input['user_id'])
                   ->whereBetween('created_at', array($date_from_formatted, $date_to_formatted));

$order = $query->get();

$online_order = $query->where('ord_type', 'Onl')->where('paid', 'Y')
                      ->whereIn('status', $param)->get();
```